# How would I read words given by the user in a file, and replace the word with asterieks from a user given msg if the word is in the file?

Tags: python

**So basically what I am trying to say is the following:
I want to read a user given file via command line arguments, then ask a user for a message that they want to be censored. If a given word in a sentence is also in the textfile they provided, then we replace the word with asterisks. Else, we print the word out.
I've got how to the basic idea, but it is not working. Help me! my code is below:**

from sys import argv
from cs50 import get_string

```
def main():


    if len(argv) != 2:
        print("provide a txtfile.")
        exit(1)

    msg = get_string("What do you want to bleep?\n")

    words = []
    finalWORDS = []

    with open(argv[1]) as bntxt:
        for line in bntxt:
            d = words.append(line.strip())
        for word in msg:
            s = msg.split()
        for same in s:
            if s == d:
                finalWORDS.append(s)
            else:
                print("no")


    print(words)
    print(s)
    print(finalWORDS)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**I am very sorry if this is confusing! I have seen many others try to do this, but they do not answer my question. If you answer this: thank you for your time and patience!**

Answer (score 0):

There are several errors in your code... Maybe you should start again from scratch, extending the program if the previous part works. Some remarks:

- `for line in bntxt`:  There should be `bntxt.readlines()`
- `for word in msg: s = msg.split()` : it does not to be in a loop, as the value is always the same (it doesn't change across read file)
- You probably want to nest all the `for`s inside, so remember the proper indentation.

Good luck!